# Child window closed after choosing a value, unable to bring the focus to parent window

Tags: windows, selenium

If i click a link on parent window, child window opens and after selecting a value in child window, the child window closes automatically and still the control is in closed window. How to bring back the control to parent window.

code :

```
Set<String> windows3 = w.getWindowHandles();
            for(String handles3 : windows3)
            {
                w.switchTo().window(handles3);
                System.out.println(w.getTitle());
            }
            w.switchTo().frame("MainFrame1");
            w.findElement(By.name("close_button")).click();
            w.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

once if i click the `close` button, the child window closed automatically. `w.close()` [`w` is the reference variable for driver class -- `WebDriver w = new FirefoxDriver();`]; is not working here. Clicking on close button in child window is mandatory. Kindly bring a solution for this

Error :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Unable to get browser (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 13 milliseconds
```

Comment: focus on parent window before closing child, then close child. Else let parent window close child and focus on itself

Comment: how to focus on parent window before closing child ?? I want to click an element in child window, once i click it will be closed automatically, then am not able to move the control to parent. If possible write your code here, it will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You would need to save the parent window handle before switching to child window and then switch back to parent window using that handle.

```
String parentWin=w.getWindowHandle();

  /* Switch Window Code */

w.switchTo().window(parentWin);
```

Statement `w.switchTo().defaultContent();` is throwing the error because you are trying to switch to default content of the closed window.

Comment: for(String handle : windows)
   {
    w.switchTo().window(handle);
   }
   System.out.println(w.getTitle());
   w.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   w.switchTo().defaultContent();
   w.switchTo().frame("menucontent");
   w.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@id='toggleTreeExpand']")).click();
   w.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   w.switchTo().frame(w.findElement(By.name("menuFr")));
   w.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='open account")).click();

Comment: What is above code for? Did my solution worked for you?

Comment: Actually there are 2 child windows, if i select a value in 2nd child window, it closes automatically and child window 1 am unable to bring the control.

Comment: So when focus is on window1, save its windowhandle and then move to window2. After window 2 closes switch to that windowhandle. If needed, save windowhandle for parent as well.

Comment: If i run the script for 5 times without changing any code, it works only for 2 times and the remaining 3 times it throws an error like Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchFrameException: No frame element found by name or id MainFrame1". why its happening like this ?

Comment: That is a separate issue of frame, not of window. Actually, frame is not available for action when selenium locates it. Try adding sleep or wait before finding the frame. That should run smooth.

Comment: Done but still, Even I have added a line like Thread.sleep(5000); but still am facing this issue. But when i run this code for 5-6 times without changing any code. Its being executed for 1 or 2 times. I dunno where the issue is

Comment: You should better edit the question with the problem you are facing adding your code as well.